# How to convert an ECDSA key to PEM format

Tags: openssl, ecdsa

I have a private raw key of **myetherwallet** with a **passphrase** "testwallet", now I am trying to convert it to a PEM format using OpenSSL following this answer.

```
echo "a140bd507a57360e2fa503298c035854f0dcb248bedabbe7a14db3920aaacf57" | xxd -r -p - | openssl ec -inform der -pubin -noout -passin pass:testwallet -text
```

But this error appears:

```
read EC key
unable to load Key
140084694296480:error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:not enough data:a_d2i_fp.c:247:
```

**UPDATE:**
I don't have the public key, instead I want to generate it so later I can also generate the Ethereum address corresponds..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are claiming your raw key is in OpenSSL's DER format, which it isn't. Also you are claming a private key is a public key, which it isn't, and claiming it's password-encrypted which is wrong either way: public keys are never encrypted and private keys in OpenSSL's 'traditional' aka 'legacy' algorithm-specific DER formats (for ECC, defined by [SECG SEC1](https://www.secg.org)) cannot be encrypted. (OTOH private keys in PKCS8 format can be password-encrypted in either DER or PEM, although PEM is more convenient. And FWIW PKCS12 format is always password-encrypted, and always DER.)

An ECC (ECDSA, ECDH, ECMQV, etc) key is always **relative to** some 'curve' (more exactly, prime-order subgroup over a curve with an identified generator aka base point). For bitcoin this is **secp256k1**, but your question doesn't say it's limited to bitcoin and this answer would require modification for other applications using other curves.

**If you also have the public key** (as an uncompressed point), you can simply use the solution from https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66594/signing-transaction-with-ssl-private-key-to-pem . Concatenate the hex strings:

```
  a pre_string : 30740201010420
  the privkey  : (32 bytes as 64 hexits) 
  a mid_string : a00706052b8104000aa144034200 (identifies secp256k1) 
  the pubkey   : (65 bytes as 130 hexits)
```

and then either convert the hex to binary and read as DER, or convert the hex (probably via binary) to base64 and wrap with `-----BEGIN/END EC PRIVATE KEY-----` lines to make it PEM.

**If you don't have the public key**, you can modify this slightly. Concatenate the hex strings

```
302e0201010420 privkey_32bytes_64hexits a00706052b8104000a
```

and convert to binary, then read into `openssl ec -inform d` . Note OpenSSL will derive the public key from the private key given the curve, but not actually store it in the PEM output, so reading with software other than OpenSSL is not guaranteed. You might need to use `openssl ec -text [-noout]` (on either PEM or DER input as convenient) to get the public key value, then go back and create the fuller encoding that includes the public key as above.

---

**ADDED:** since you seem not to comprehend the words in the answer, I'll lay this out in as much detail as I can.

The value `a140bd507a57360e2fa503298c035854f0dcb248bedabbe7a14db3920aaacf57` is the raw private key represented in hex. A secp256k1 private value is 32 bytes in binary; when binary is represented in hex each byte takes two hex digits, so 32 bytes takes 64 hex digits. All of this value is the raw private key. There is no part consisting of 25 digits OR 25 bytes that has any useful meaning whatever. Do not take any 25-anything part of this value.

To construct the OpenSSL/SECG representation of a **private key with no public key**, put the hex string representing the private key -- all of it, without modification -- between the two other hex strings I showed as the second option:

```
 302e0201010420 a140bd507a57360e2fa503298c035854f0dcb248bedabbe7a14db3920aaacf57 a00706052b8104000a
```

Then convert this combined hex string to binary, and read the result into `openssl ec -inform d`:

```
$ echo 302e0201010420 a140bd507a57360e2fa503298c035854f0dcb248bedabbe7a14db3920aaacf57 a00706052b8104000a | xxd -r -p >48101258.1
$ openssl ec -inform d <48101258.1
read EC key
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQEEIKFAvVB6VzYOL6UDKYwDWFTw3LJIvtq756FNs5IKqs9XoAcGBSuBBAAK
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The result is PEM format -- but PEM format not including the public key, which you indicate you want. To see the fields including the derived public key, add `-text`; to see only the fields and not the PEM output, add `-noout`:

```
$ openssl ec -inform d <48101258.1 -text -noout
read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    a1:40:bd:50:7a:57:36:0e:2f:a5:03:29:8c:03:58:
    54:f0:dc:b2:48:be:da:bb:e7:a1:4d:b3:92:0a:aa:
    cf:57
pub:
    04:20:ea:6d:8c:e7:bc:bb:48:33:69:b2:91:1c:75:
    e5:60:2a:34:28:be:44:96:e9:7f:14:ad:52:fd:4a:
    6a:a0:e3:60:83:9c:6e:db:32:2a:22:55:7c:70:1e:
    d0:fa:1e:06:cf:57:4f:be:17:bd:6a:85:51:69:c5:
    65:96:72:cf:a9
ASN1 OID: secp256k1
```

Now if you want a PEM-format key **including the public key**, take *both* the hex strings for the private key (all 64 digits) AND the newly-shown hex value for the public key, and plug them in to my *first* option. Also note an ECC public key is a curve point which can be in two forms, compressed or uncompressed; the form generated here is uncompressed. If you need compressed, I'll add that later. A secp256k1 point in uncompressed form is 65 bytes, represented in hex as 130 hex digits. (Which `openssl ec` formats as 4 lines each of 15 bytes with 5 bytes left over.)

```
$ echo 30740201010420 a140bd507a57360e2fa503298c035854f0dcb248bedabbe7a14db3920aaacf57 a00706052b8104000aa144034200 \
> 04:20:ea:6d:8c:e7:bc:bb:48:33:69:b2:91:1c:75: e5:60:2a:34:28:be:44:96:e9:7f:14:ad:52:fd:4a: \
> 6a:a0:e3:60:83:9c:6e:db:32:2a:22:55:7c:70:1e: d0:fa:1e:06:cf:57:4f:be:17:bd:6a:85:51:69:c5: \
> 65:96:72:cf:a9 | xxd -r -p >48101258.2
$ # note xxd -r -p ignores the colons; other hex programs may need them removed instead
$ openssl ec -inform d <48101258.2
read EC key
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIKFAvVB6VzYOL6UDKYwDWFTw3LJIvtq756FNs5IKqs9XoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEIOptjOe8u0gzabKRHHXlYCo0KL5Elul/FK1S/UpqoONgg5xu2zIqIlV8
cB7Q+h4Gz1dPvhe9aoVRacVllnLPqQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

---

ADDED 2019-02 for DavidS: as correctly shown in [k06a's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213805)

- the first part of my midstring (or the entire suffix for my private-only option) `a00706052b8104000a` is a context-tag and length `a007` for an OID tag and length `0605` containing `2b8104000a` which is [1.3.132.0.10 which is secp256k1](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.132.0.10) and
- the remainder of my midstring `a144034200` is a context tag and length containing the tag length and unused-bits header for a BITSTRING which is the raw publickey as an uncompressed point.

To do **secp256r1** aka P-256 or prime256v1 instead, you need to change the AlgId.OID to [1.2.840.10045.3.1.7](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.10045.3.1.7) which is encoded as `a00a 0608 2a8648ce3d030107`. The privatekey and publickey values for p256r1 are the same sizes as for p256k1, but the AlgId is longer, so you also need to change the length of the outer SEQUENCE giving

```
30770201010420 privatekey32bytes # note 77 
a00a06082a8648ce3d030107 a144034200 publicpoint65bytes
```

Comment: I have to admit I am lost now, my understanding is the last 25 character from this key `a140bd507a57360e2fa503298c035854f0dcb248bedabbe7a14db3920aaacf57` is the private key?

Comment: @HAßdøµ The 'raw' private key, normally used by bitcoin (and related) wallets because the curve is implied, is actually 32 bytes, but you have it represented in hexadecimal as 64 hex digits (hexits); other representations are possible but hex is easiest to manipulate. All 64 hexits (or 32 bytes) are the raw key and there is nothing else in that representation; that's _why_ you need to add the other pieces to build the SECG format(s) OpenSSL uses.

Comment: So as first step how I can extract the private and import it in OpenSSL? I tried to take the last 25 character, convert it to binary then base64, concatenate with `-----BEGIN` and `-----END` but it still fail to be accepted by OPENSSL.

Comment: @HAßdøµ I don't know where you get this '25 character' from, but see substantially expanded answer.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, how did you get to `a00706052b8104000aa144034200`? I need the same thing but for secp256r1.

Comment: any steps to convert the public key to pem format? what header I should use? here is my public key: 4bb5f0c58cc71806ec4d228b730dd252947e679cce05f71d434787fe228f14c799cf8965780bb308aa722ac179bfa5fd57592a72cbdcfe89ab61ad5d77251186d

Comment: dave_thompson_085/All,  will you be able to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218946/convert-a-plain-public-key-to-pem/56225861?noredirect=1#comment99256521_56225861. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magnificent answer. 2 years later, a random soul really appreciates the effort

Answer (score 4):

[Elliptic Curve Private Key Format](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5915.txt):

```
ECPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
 version        INTEGER { ecPrivkeyVer1(1) } (ecPrivkeyVer1),
 privateKey     OCTET STRING,
 parameters [0] ECParameters {{ NamedCurve }} OPTIONAL,
 publicKey  [1] BIT STRING OPTIONAL
}
```

So `publicKey` is `OPTIONAL` and theoretically can be missed.

Here is example of my DER secp256k1 private key:

```
30740201 01042092 E768CB72 0DC16924 27D156DB 39630748 0D1507B9 A4958450
2574B9A0 922F4BA0 0706052B 8104000A A1440342 00041954 9737B704 D1789A57
82E3430E 8259F904 71326081 054854D2 A5D096F9 686D05B0 30D98BA3 C60C056E
204CEF61 C0AC5B53 A9A6B9A0 5AFF9DA2 6CA4B65B 2E84
```

Trying to decompose:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in <(echo "30740201 01042092 E768CB72 0DC16924 27D156DB 39630748 0D1507B9 A4958450 2574B9A0 922F4BA0 0706052B 8104000A A1440342 00041954 9737B704 D1789A57 82E3430E 8259F904 71326081 054854D2 A5D096F9 686D05B0 30D98BA3 C60C056E 204CEF61 C0AC5B53 A9A6B9A0 5AFF9DA2 6CA4B65B 2E84" | xxd -r -p)
```

ASN.1 parsing result:

```
 0:d=0  hl=2 l= 116 cons: SEQUENCE          
 2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
 5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:92E768CB720DC1692427D156DB396307480D1507B9A49584502574B9A0922F4B
39:d=1  hl=2 l=   7 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
41:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :secp256k1
48:d=1  hl=2 l=  68 cons: cont [ 1 ]        
50:d=2  hl=2 l=  66 prim: BIT STRING
```

Detailed (see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/66622/22979):

```
30 - ASN.1
74 - Length of all following bytes (116 bytes)

  02 - Type (integer)
  01 - Length of integer (1 byte)
  01 - Value of integer (1)

  04 - Type (octet string)
  20 - Length of string (32 bytes)
  92E768CB720DC1692427D156DB396307480D1507B9A49584502574B9A0922F4B - Private Key

  A0 - Tag 0
  07 - Length of tag (7 bytes)
  06 - Type (Object ID)
  05 - Length of the Object ID (5 bytes)
  2b 81 04 00 0a - The object ID of the curve secp256k1

  A1 - Tag 1
  44 - Length of tag (68 bytes)
  03 - Type – Bit string
  42 - Length of the bit string (66 bytes)
  00 - ???
  04 - Uncompressed Public Key
  19549737B704D1789A5782E3430E8259F90471326081054854D2A5D096F9686D - Public Key X coord
  05B030D98BA3C60C056E204CEF61C0AC5B53A9A6B9A05AFF9DA26CA4B65B2E84 - Public Key Y coord
```

I removed Public Key object and fixed ASN.1 length from 116 bytes (0x74) to 46 bytes (0x2e):

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in <(echo "302E020101042092E768CB720DC1692427D156DB396307480D1507B9A49584502574B9A0922F4BA00706052B8104000A" | xxd -r -p)
```

Got result:

```
 0:d=0  hl=2 l=  46 cons: SEQUENCE          
 2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
 5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:92E768CB720DC1692427D156DB396307480D1507B9A49584502574B9A0922F4B
39:d=1  hl=2 l=   7 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
41:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :secp256k1
```

Trying to get Public Key:

```
$ openssl ec -inform DER -in <(echo "302E020101042092E768CB720DC1692427D156DB396307480D1507B9A49584502574B9A0922F4BA00706052B8104000A" | xxd -r -p)
```

Result:

```
read EC key
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQEEIJLnaMtyDcFpJCfRVts5YwdIDRUHuaSVhFAldLmgki9LoAcGBSuBBAAK
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

One more try:

```
$ openssl ec -inform DER -text -in <(echo "302E020101042092E768CB720DC1692427D156DB396307480D1507B9A49584502574B9A0922F4BA00706052B8104000A" | xxd -r -p)
```

Result:

```
read EC key
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I used OSX system `openssl` – looks like it is `LibreSSL 2.2.7`.

**Added:** Reported a bug to LibreSSL: https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/395
**UPDATE:** In latest macOS 10.15.1 preinstalled openssl (LibreSSL 2.8.3) have this bug fixed.

Then I installed latest openssl: `brew install openssl`

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2n/bin/openssl ec -inform DER -text -noout -in <(echo "302E020101042092E768CB720DC1692427D156DB396307480D1507B9A49584502574B9A0922F4BA00706052B8104000A" | xxd -r -p)
```

And got:

```
read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    00:92:e7:68:cb:72:0d:c1:69:24:27:d1:56:db:39:
    63:07:48:0d:15:07:b9:a4:95:84:50:25:74:b9:a0:
    92:2f:4b
pub: 
    04:19:54:97:37:b7:04:d1:78:9a:57:82:e3:43:0e:
    82:59:f9:04:71:32:60:81:05:48:54:d2:a5:d0:96:
    f9:68:6d:05:b0:30:d9:8b:a3:c6:0c:05:6e:20:4c:
    ef:61:c0:ac:5b:53:a9:a6:b9:a0:5a:ff:9d:a2:6c:
    a4:b6:5b:2e:84
ASN1 OID: secp256k1
```

Final solution:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2n/bin/openssl ec -inform DER -text -noout -in <(cat <(echo -n "302e0201010420") <(echo -n "***") <(echo -n "a00706052b8104000a") | xxd -r -p) 2>/dev/null | tail -6 | head -5 | sed 's/[ :]//g' | tr -d '\n' && echo
```

Replace `***` with a hexademical private key.

Comment: Since I only now noticed, the 00 between 03 42 and the publickey (uncompressed point) is the number of unused aka padding bits in the BITSTRING; see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129490/why-are-there-leading-0x00-bytes-in-the-subjectpublickey-field-of-a-der-x.509-