# Create EC private key from input keying material in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I'd like to derive an elliptic curve private key from input keying material (a master key). Is this possible?

#### Attempts

Node's crypto function, [`crypto.generateKeyPair`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback) does not accept input keying material, and [`crypto.createPrivateKey`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key) only converts a .pem to Node's native KeyObject.

I also can't find a way to do this in OpenSSL using [`ecparam`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ecparam.html). The `-rand` flag seems promising but isn't widely  available (it's not on my machine).

### Why / Details

I need to create a number of secrets and want have all of them derived from a single master key. This is analogous to HKDF.

I'm using the keys for ECDSA with curve P-384 (`secp384r1`).

Comment: As you know a private key is just a large number which is used in conjunction with the curve generator point to evaluate a public point on the curve. Therefore I would probably just use a cryptographically secure HBKDF with an incremented nonce to generate key material. Not familiar with generic node crypto API but it looks like you can generate a key manually using key material:https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised you think `ecparam -rand file -genkey ...` is rare; it's in every upstream version back *at least* to 0.9.8 in 2005, and it's not one of the things that can be omitted by a build (configure) option, so your machine must have one weird version. But it doesn't matter because `-rand` doesn't do what you want; it *adds* the file data to the RNG 'pool' but does not *replace* it, so it doesn't give you deterministic key generation.

As Woodstock commented, for all practical purposes a raw P-384 private key is just 384 bits from any good random generator, or deterministically from any uniform random function. Technically you should exclude zero and values greater than or equal to the (sub)group order n, but those exclusions are so small relative to 2^384 that there is essentially no chance a good random choice will hit them during the lifetime of the Earth, and perhaps of the universe. You might want to look at how Bitcoin 'hierarchical deterministic' key derivation aka [BIP 32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) works, although of course that does 256-bit keys for secp256k1.

That leaves you the problem of converting the raw key to a form usable by nodejs crypto (which is a fairly thin wrapping of openssl library) and/or openssl commandline. To do this follow the principles of [How to convert an ECDSA key to PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101258/how-to-convert-an-ecdsa-key-to-pem-format) which is in turn based on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66594/signing-transaction-with-ssl-private-key-to-pem except use the OID and size(s) for P-384 instead of secp256k1. Specifically, concatenate

- the 7 bytes represented in hex by 303e0201010430
- the 48 bytes (384 bits) of the raw private key
- the 9 bytes represented in hex by a00706052b81040022 (for P-384 aka secp384r1)

Depending on your language(s) or tool(s) you might handle these values directly, or concatenate the hex representations and then convert to binary. The result is the 'DER' (binary) form of the algorithm-specific (SEC1) private key (only), which can be read by nodejs 11 or 12 `crypto.createPrivateKey( {key:(data), format:'der', type:'sec1'} )` and also by commandline `openssl ec -inform der`.

If you prefer textlike things (e.g. for cut&paste), convert the DER above to base64, break into lines of 64 chars (other than the last), and add lines `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----` before and `-----END EC PRIVATE KEY------` after. This is PEM format and can be read by `createPrivateKey` without any other options, and by `openssl ec` without any option.